# Force minimum site width for mobile devices

Tags: responsive

A client has a site using a responsive theme and they want to disable the mobile version, so that mobile visitors will see the tablet version but zoomed out.

I have attempted to simply alter the breakpoints that apply to mobile visitors, but by the theme developers own admission due to how the style sheet is set up this is very complicated and time consuming.

So I have started looking for a more straightforward way of doing this by forcing a minimum window size for mobile visitors. Possibly with a function that detects if the browser width is under 700px, then if so resizes the window size to 1000px? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {
  var b = document.body
    , w = window.innerWidth;
  if( w < 700 ) {
    b.style.maxWidth = '1000px';
    b.style.minWidth = '1000px';
    b.style.overflowX = 'scroll';
  } return;
}
```

Since your question is migrated from WPSE I'd recommend adding this script with a custom plugin or this code in your child theme's functions file:

```
add_action("wp_footer", function() { 
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
      var b = document.body
        , w = window.innerWidth;
      if( w < 700 ) {
        b.style.maxWidth = '1000px';
        b.style.minWidth = '1000px';
        b.style.overflowX = 'scroll';
      } else {
        b.style.maxWidth = null;
        b.style.minWidth = null;
        b.style.overflowX = null;
      } return;
    }
    </script>
  <?php
});
```

Basically screens under `700px` width will have a horizontal scroll bar to scroll through the content.

I added [`onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize) event properly hoping that would help in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Samuel. This worked, but I had to remove the onresize event as it was causing issues when zooming out on iPhones.